# Button click issue on a string array

Tags: android, button

When I select an item with a spinner and click the button, I want to create a program that generates an array of choices with the spinner, such as 5 to add random numbers and float them in a textview. There are no errors, but when running, click the button to exit the program. Which part is the problem? The entire code is as follows:

```
public class ArrayAdderActivity extends Activity {

    static int numnum;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(

                this, R.array.planets, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);
        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String num=s.getSelectedItem().toString();
                numnum = Integer.parseInt(num);

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int array1[] = null;
                String string1[];
                for (int i = 0; i<numnum; i++){
                    array1[i]=((int)(Math.random()));
                    text1.setText("num #"+(i+1)+": "+array1[i]+"/n");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: post your logcat errors

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your `array1` inside `OnClickListener`. Try to initialize first and then use it.

```
int[] array1 = new int[numnum];
```

Also you declare `string1` there but not initialize. If you use `string1` there you have to initialize it before use.